# How to override the environment variables for Jenkins slave when adding new slave

Tags: jenkins

Configured automatic slaves for couple jobs on Jenkins using [ec2 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin). I need to override couple of environment variables for the slave before connecting to master. Here is the init script that used to run before it connect as slave. What am I doing wrong. Can someone please help me?

PROBLEM:
I'm able to launch a slave,But unable to set environment variables for that slave.

GOAL:
Install maven-3.2.5 (set home directory to /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5),
Environment variables: (name: DISPLAY, value: :1),
                       (name: PATH, value: $PATH:/usr/local/bin)

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo mkdir /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5
if [ -d /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5 ]; then
    if [ ! -f /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz ]; then
        wget -nd -O /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz
    fi
    tar -xvf /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.5-bin.tar.gz
    sudo mv apache-maven-3.2.5 /opt/
    sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5
fi
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
DISPLAY=:1
MAVEN_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.2.5
```

Jenkins version:1.656
Amazon EC2 plugin:1.31

Comment: Isn't it easier to specify path to Maven in Jenkins config (Global Tool Configuration)?

Comment: Yes it is. On Jenkins master Maven installation already specified, But it is in different location. I need to override those global variables for a Jenkins slave.

Comment: It is possible to specify another Maven location. You only need to choose the right one on a job configuration page.
As for environment variables it can be a bug of ec2 plugin. Or something like EnvInject cleans your environment. I would check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your own environment variables you can use [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to override system variables like PATH, but you can create symlinks for mvn executables in `/usr/local/bin` or any default location in your linux distributive.